# Pandas efficient resampling

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe look like this:

```
times = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2020-08-05','2020-08-12', '2020-08-16', '2020-08-22', '2020-08-30', '2020-09-11', '2020-09-20']))
event = [100, 90, 77, 62, 39, 30, 30]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Active_Covid_Cases': event}, index=times)
```

I want to analyse how trend changes week over week.

My expected output should look like: (WW: Work Week)

```
WW   Active_Case   times
0    100         2020-08-05
1     90         2020-08-12
2     ..         2020-08-19
3     ..         2020-08-26
```

WW0 corresponds to the first date (2020-08-05) and thus, WW1 would be 2020-08-12 and so on...

I am doing resampling using:  `df2 = df.resample('W')`  But, what more to add to get into Work week format???

Comment: if you have one data point at every week why you just don't try df.reset_index()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2 = df.resample('7D', closed='right', label='right').sum()

df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
df2.rename(columns={'index': 'times'}, inplace=True)

df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
df2.rename(columns={'index': 'WW'}, inplace=True)

df2

   WW      times  Active_Covid_Cases
0   0 2020-08-05                 100
1   1 2020-08-12                  90
2   2 2020-08-19                  77
3   3 2020-08-26                  62
4   4 2020-09-02                  39
5   5 2020-09-09                   0
6   6 2020-09-16                  30
7   7 2020-09-23                  30
```

Comment: 5 2020-09-09                   0
Why do you thing there is zero for row 6? How can that be improved?

Comment: There is no data for that week in your data frame, i.e. you have no data points between the 2nd of September and the 9th of September.